# Set different paths to buttons

Tags: reactjs, button, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework and I am trying to set two different paths to two different `<EditButton/>`.

So far I have created my custom component, that renders buttons as the actions component.

For example, I want one button to have a path to `edit/somepath` and the other button to have a default edit path `/edit`.

So far I have tried this:

```
   var getId = this.props.data;
   if (getId !== undefined) {
    var yey = getId["id"];
   }
   return (
    <CardActions>
     {bulkActions && React.cloneElement(bulkActions, {
      basePath,
      filterValues,
      resource,
      selectedIds,
      onUnselectItems
     })}
     <EditButton basePath={basePath}/>
     <EditButton
      label="Upravit JSON"
      basePath={yey}
     />
    </CardActions>
   );
```

The first button, which should have the simple `/edit` path now redirects to `/basePath/undefined`. And the second button redirects to `basePath/edit/somepath/edit/somepath/undefined` which I found really weird since my variable `yey` stores only string `edit/somepath`.

I am really stuck here, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used `react-admin`, but looking at the repo and source code, the component looks like that:

```
const EditButton = ({
  basePath = '',
  label = 'ra.action.edit',
  record = {},
  icon = <ContentCreate />,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Button
    component={Link}
    to={linkToRecord(basePath, record.id)}
    label={label}
    onClick={stopPropagation}
    {...rest}
>
    {icon}
  </Button>
);
```

So it looks like the `to` property concatenates your `basePath` and a `record.id` from the props - I am guessing that is what's missing in your code!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something similar, I needed to wrap the `EditButton` with a div for CSS puposes and lost the record context (it was `undefined`).

So I extracted it to `CustomEditButton` and i'm passing it `basePath` & `record.id` on it's `to` props, here's a tested & working example:

```
const CustomEditButton = ({ record, basePath }) => {
  return <div>
    <EditButton to={`${basePath}/${record.id}`}/>
  </div>
}
```